# Form with radio buttons + logic

Tags: javascript, html, forms, logic

I'm trying to create a form (kind of like a quiz) that uses radio buttons and logic to generate and display different diagnostic results. Here is what I have for some of the form structure (there are many more options and the logic is more weighty in the real version):

```
  <form action='index.php' method='post'>
  Q1: Does Patient experience Symptom X?
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Q1Y"/> Yes</label> &nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Q1N"/> No</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  Q2: Does Patient experience Symptom Y?
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="Q2Y"/> Yes</label> &nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="Q2N"/> No</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  Q3: Does Patient experience Symptom Z?
  <br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="Q3Y"/> Yes</label> &nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="Q3N"/> No</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="See Result"/>
  <br/>
```

How do I set up the rest of the logic such that:

```
If (Q1Y && Q2Y){ 
Diagnosis = A; 
}

If (Q2Y && Q3Y){ 
Diagnosis = B; 
}
```

Ideally, the diagnosis would store in a variable then show on the current page when the user clicks submit on the form.

Comment: You are trying to do this on form submit with PHP, or after they click the three options with JS, or stop the form submission with JS and just have JS run the logic as well? Knowing what is in `index.php` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(($_POST['Q1']=='Q1Y') && ($_POST['Q2']=='Q2Y'))
{
// Your Logic
}
if(($_POST['Q2']=='Q2Y') && ($_POST['Q3']=='Q3Y'))
{
// Your Logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested objects to hold the results of all the combinations of answers.

```
var allDiagnosis = {
    Q1Y: {
        Q2Y: {
            Q3Y: 'A',
            Q3N: 'B'
        },
        Q2N: {
            Q3Y: 'C',
            Q3N: 'D'
        },
    Q1N: {
        Q2Y: {
            Q3Y: 'E',
            Q3N: 'F'
        },
        Q2N: {
            Q3Y: 'G',
            Q3N: 'H'
        }
    }
}
```

Then get the value of each input, and do:

```
var diagnosis = allDiagnosis[value1][value2][value3];
```